# Вин. или род. падеж при использовании глагола несоверш. вида в прошедшем времени?

Tags: окончания

1. «Он не выпускал **гитару** из рук» или «Он не выпускал **гитары** из рук»?
2. «Он не выпускал **ножа** из рук» или «Он не выпускал **нож** из рук»?
3. «Он не выпускал **ключ** из рук» или «Он не выпускал **ключа** из рук»?

Comment: Это не именительный, а винительный падеж в вашем вопросе.

Comment: @Третийглаз, спасибо, поправил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Если при глаголе кроме данного существительного должно быть еще одно
> зависимое существительное или прилагательное, то используется
> винительный падеж: <...> *не прочитал статью за вечер*.

[Источник](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters?id=67)

Comment: не совсем понимаю это правило. Подходит ли оно к данному вопросу? Не считая того, что в национальном корпусе при подобных примерах используется именно родительный падеж: "...наравне с плотниками не выпускал из рук топора.", "Советскому солдату, который на протяжении всех этих сорока с лишним лет не выпускал из рук оружия...", "Она послала отцу воздушный поцелуй. Я не выпускал рукава отцовской шубы...". Короче, я запутался.

Comment: @Theej у Д. Э. Розенталя на эту тему обширнее написано: https://goo.su/0Dp0vvS. Я думаю, что ответила верно, но прочитайте сами, там очень много нюансов, возможно, что-то и не заметила.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки, ознакомлюсь.